# Show that there is no entire function such that $f(\frac 1n)=\frac{n}{3n-2},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, entire-functions

> Show that there is no entire function such that $f(\frac
>  1n)=\frac{n}{3n-2},\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

**My attempt:**

Suppose that there is such entire function $f$. Define $g:z\mapsto \frac{z^{-1}}{3z^{-1}-2}$. Then $f(\frac 1n)=g(\frac 1n),\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. This implies that $f=g$ on $\mathbb{C}$. The function $g$, however, is not entire since it has a pole in $3/2$ - a contradiction! Therefore, such entire function does not exist.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct idea.

Comment: Yes, you can use the identity theorem: If two holomorphic functions $f$ and $g$ on a domain $D$ agree on a set $S$ which has an accumulation point $c$ in $D$, then $f = g$ on $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You cannot deduce that $f=g$ simply from the fact that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f\left(\frac1n\right)=g\left(\frac1n\right).\tag1$$For instance, if $f$ is the null function and $g(z)=\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)$, but in that case you *don't* have $f=g$, right?!

Instead, define$$\begin{array}{rccc}h\colon&D_{\frac32}\left(0\right)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\frac1{3-2z}.\end{array}$$Then $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f\left(\frac1n\right)=h\left(\frac1n\right)$ and so$$f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac 1n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}h\left(\frac 1n\right)=h(0)$$and therefore$$\left\{z\in D_{\frac32}\left(0\right)\,\middle|\,f(z)=h(z)\right\}\supset\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}.$$Since the set $\left\{z\in D_{\frac32}\left(0\right)\,\middle|\,f(z)=h(z)\right\}$ contains a non-isolated point ($0$), it follows from the identity theorem that$$\left(\forall z\in D_{\frac32}(0)\right):f(z)=h(z).$$But $\lim_{z\to\frac32}f(z)=f\left(\frac32\right)$, whreas the limit $\lim_{z\to\frac32}h(z)$ doesn't exist (in $\mathbb C$).

Comment: *You cannot deduce that $f=g$ simply from the fact that...* But here both $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic around $z=0$: for $f$ it's the assumption and for $g$ it's obvious. I don't see how your solution adds essential ingredients to the original approach.

Comment: The null function and the function $g(z)=\sin\left(\frac\pi z\right)$ are also holomorphic around $z=0$, but your argument doesn't work for them, right? Being holomorphic *around* $0$ isn't enough. They have to be defined on an open set to which $0$ belongs.

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong word. By "around $0$" I meant "holomorphic at $0$", which implies holomorphic in a small open disc containing $0$. Anyway, this is clearly satisfied by our $f$ and $g$ here.

Comment: It would be nice if would say explicitly whether or not you agree with my argument.

Comment: Of course your answer is logically correct, but I think it's just a more proper writing of the idea presented in the original post, in which the OP only presented the rough idea of a proof. So your leading sentence *No, it is not correct* sounds a bit misleading, as if the posted idea were totally wrong.

Comment: But it *is* wrong, since $g$ is undefined at $0$.

Comment: I'm sure the OP knows that $g=\frac 1{3-2z}$.